# Mule ESB org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied:

Tags: soap, https, mule, cxf, esb

I am using Mule 3.7 CE. The message flow basically uses CXF proxies to direct SOAP based requests over Https to the end client. When a request is sent to Mule it is throwing an exception as below

```
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://tempuri.org/}Service#{http://tempuri.org/}VerifyCompleteRegistration has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}TransportBinding: TLS is not enabled
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}HttpsToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}TransportToken
       at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionInfoMap.checkEffectivePolicy(AssertionInfoMap.java:179) ~[cxf-rt-ws-policy-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
       at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyVerificationInInterceptor.handle(PolicyVerificationInInterceptor.java:101) ~[cxf-rt-ws-policy-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
       at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AbstractPolicyInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractPolicyInterceptor.java:44) ~[cxf-rt-ws-policy-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
```

Just to mention TLS is Enabled with configurations set to use https and all the configuration related to TLS (keystore and truststore) is also in place on Mule ESB. Below is the snippet from WSDL for security policy.

```
<sp:TransportBinding  xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
 <sp:TransportToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportToken>
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Basic256/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<sp:Layout>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Strict/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Layout>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportBinding>
```

I am not sure what needs to be changed in order for this to work. Any help would be much appreciated.